# How to check if the system time is valid or not in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux

Our devices have Linux OS installed on them. When the box reboots, it will contact the servers, get the time from servers and this time will be set as local time on the device. Can any one please let me know if there is any way to check whether this time is valid or not.

Comment: what is an "invalid" time for you?

Comment: Does `time()` return -1?

Comment: There is no such thing as invalid time - it is either current time, time in the future, or time in the past.

Comment: @chux, my man page for time(2) doesn't concur: 'On error, ((time_t) -1) is returned, and errno is set appropriately... ERRORS  EFAULT t points outside your accessible address space.' - which indicates the only error which can be triggered is bad address of t.

Comment: @Hayt Any time other than current time on the box is invalid.

Comment: Hopefully, you're using [`ntp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) for this and the OS-supplied tools already built for this purpose, and didn't reinvent them.

Comment: @kadina *Any time other than current time on the box is invalid.* And how could a process running on such a computer tell that the time on that computer is invalid?

Comment: Current time is actually non-existent.

Comment: Perhaps ask another local server to make sure the first server was not lying? Or ask all of them and take the mean, discarding those grossly adrift.

Comment: How to tell whether a clock is right: Compare it to another clock you trust.

What do you not trust? The servers you're getting your time from? (In which case why use them?) Or do you not trust the box itself properly updating its time? (In which case, manually compare the times. You should only have to do that once. Once you've verified the mechanisms work, you can probably trust it going forward.)

Comment: @Altainia: I understood your logic. In our case, UI will ask middleware whether the current time on the box is valid or not. We can't simply return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, `time()` returns `(time_t)(-1)` to indicate "the calendar time is not available."

If `mkitme()` fails, it returns `(time_t)(-1)` when "the calendar time cannot be represented".

Testing the result of `time()` may be a sufficient "way to check whether this time is valid or not."

> The value `(time_t)(-1)` is returned if the calendar time is not
>   available.  C11dr §7.27.2.4 3

Comment: This C, and most likely, mean underlying system doesn't support corresponding syscall. It doesn't mean system time is in any way 'incorrect'

Comment: @SergeyA Answer updated with ref.

Comment: edited my comment :D